# Same Tagbase and Post Name in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

On my Wordpress blog I have a page named "Products" and a sub page named "MyProduct":

```
example.com/products/myproduct
```

I also have a tagbase named as "products" so my tags in blog posts look like this:

```
example.com/products/tag1
example.com/products/tag2
example.com/products/tag3
 ...
```

I updated today to the newest wordpress version and if I open
example.com/products/myproduct
I receive a 404 error.

If I chage the tagbase from "products" to something different then it works, but then the example.com/products/tag1 [...] are not working anymore..
**Any ideas how to use the same name for tagbase and page name?** i could change it for both but i have a lot of sites indexed by google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  When you set a taxonomy or custom post type name, it becomes reserved for that.  You cannot also have a page with the same slug.  You will need to change one or the other.